# Select para calcular todos de registros e total de registro por uma condição

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela de vendas por usuário, que liga o user_id, product_name e valor de vendas.

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta para devolver quantos produtos foram vendidos por usuário e quantos produtos com mais de 1000 reais foram vendidos por usuário, em apenas um select.

```
SELECT
  sl.user_id,
  count(sl.user_id) as total_records,
  count(sl.sale_value) > 1000 as total_goal_achieved
FROM SALES sl
GROUP BY 1
```

Pretendo criar uma tabela temporária com esses dados.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma solução é fazer duas queries e juntá-las com um LEFT JOIN. Veja exemplo:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE example;
use example;
CREATE TABLE sales (id INT, product_name VARCHAR(100), VALOR INT);
INSERT INTO sales (id,product_name,valor)
VALUES (1,'CAFÉ',1200);
INSERT INTO sales (id,product_name,valor)
VALUES (2,'cerveja',500);
INSERT INTO sales (id,product_name,valor)
VALUES (2,'macarrao',3000);
INSERT INTO sales (id,product_name,valor)
VALUES (3,'vinho',12500);
INSERT INTO sales (id,product_name,valor)
VALUES (4,'azeitona',250);

SELECT id, total, COALESCE(totalm1000,0) as totalm1000
    FROM
    (SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT(product_name)) as total
    FROM example.sales
    GROUP BY id) as T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id as id2, COUNT(DISTINCT(product_name)) as totalm1000
    FROM example.sales
    WHERE valor>1000
    GROUP BY id2) as T2
    ON id=id2
```

Retorna:

```
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | total | totalm1000 |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |     1 |          1 |
|    2 |     2 |          1 |
|    3 |     1 |          1 |
|    4 |     1 |          0 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

A primeira query retorna o total de produtos vendidos por id, a segunda retorna o total de produtos vendidos com valor superior a 1000 por id.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda Lucas, funcionou dessa forma. Estou a dois dias tentando resolver esse problema.

Comment: quem deu o downvote se importa em justificar?